# why is my primarylinks menu is adding classes only for some items?

Tags: css, drupal, class, hyperlink

I have 2 menus defined, and I want to style them...
As I'm continuing a previous made drupal there is a menu that assigns classes to each entry (haven't discovered how it does that), 
it's outputs something like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="leaf first"><a title="" class="flores" href="/huerto-urbano/flores">Flores</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="" class="plantas" href="/huerto-urbano/plantas">Plantas</a></li>
<li class="leaf last"><a title="" class="verduras" href="/huerto-urbano/verduras">Verduras</a></li>
</ul>
```

notice the class="flores"?
now I've created another menu similar to that but the class="XXXX" disapeares..why?

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li class="leaf first"><a title="" href="/ca/huerto-urbano/flores">Flors</a></li>
 <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/ca/huerto-urbano/plantas">Plantes</a></li>
 <li class="leaf last"><a title="" href="/ca/huerto-urbano/verduras">Verdures</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by searching the template.php located in the theme directory for themed menu item functions.  If the theme name is 'plants', for example, then search for the functions plants_menu_item or plants_menu_item_link.  The logic to add the class attribute may be in there.

Comment: Hi PartySoft. Were they there?  Did this help?

Answer (score 0):

The second menu is for a different language. What you should do is check if the problem is because of the translate module. Multilanguage set up looks to be the culprit.